# Skip every third number

Tags: c++, loops, include, counter, iostream

My assignment is to print a set of numbers from min to max (the user inputs min and mix) but every third number to print an "x" instead. I'm not sure how to set it up. My friend suggested using count++ but i can't get it to work properly. It runs but it doesn't display any X's.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void no_5_count_from_min_to_max_skip_two(int min, int max);
int main()
{

    int min;
    int max;
    int first;
    int second; 

    cout<<"Enter first number:";
    cin>>first;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter second number:";
    cin>>second;
    cout<<endl;

    if (first>second){
        max = first;
        min = second;
    }
    else{
        max = second;
        min = first;
    }

    no_5_count_from_min_to_max_skip_two(min,max);

    return 0;
}

void no_5_count_from_min_to_max_skip_two(int min, int max){
    cout<<"5.Counting from min to max but skip two:";
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=min; i<=max; i++){
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        if (count==3){
            cout<<setw(4)<<"X";
            count = 0;
        }
        cout<<setw(4)<<i;
    }
cout<<endl;
```

}

Comment: `int count = 0;` recreates and resets `count` everytime through the loop. Move that to outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `count` before loop, as in your code you create new one on every iteration, and print X instead of `i` not together:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=min; i<=max; i++){
    if (++count==3){
        cout<<setw(4)<<"X";
        count = 0;
    } else // print i only when X is not printed
        cout<<setw(4)<<i;
}
```

Comment: At last!  Someone who actually solves the problem without introducing another operator that doesn't actually avoid the need to do an if!

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder of a division operation. `count++` is executed each loop thus the statement `count % 3` returns 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, etc. for each loop iteration.

When the result is `0` you know it is time to print `'X'`. If not, print `i`.

Remember to start `count` at `1` so you don't print `'X'` the first iteration.

```
void no_5_count_from_min_to_max_skip_two(int min, int max)
{
    cout << "5.Counting from min to max but skip two:";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = min, count = 1; i <= max; i++, count++)
    {
        if ((count % 3) == 0)
            cout << setw(4) << "X";
        else
            cout << setw(4) << i;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: In place of `count` you could use `(i - max + 1)`

Comment: Not `(i - min + 1)`?

Comment: @TonyDelroy - You are correct. It should be this: 


In place of `count` you could use `(i - min + 1)`